# How to see log in docker with python api?

Tags: python, api, docker

When I build a docker image with command line:

```
docker build -t x .
```

I can see the process log in terminal.

But with the python API, it doesnt't show anything.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import docker
import os

route = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

client = docker.from_env()

client.images.build(
    path=route,
    tag="al3x609/nvnc:latest",
    rm=True
)
```

How can I see it in realtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html) the build returns:

> Returns:   The first item is the Image object for the image that was
>   build. The second item is a generator of the build logs as
>   JSON-decoded objects

Try something like:

```
(imageObj, buildlog) = client.images.build(
   [...]
```

Then you can iterate throuhg buildlog:

```
for logline in buildlog:
    print logline
```

Comment: Is it possible to see the logs in the real time? client.images.build is blocking so only when it is done (can take a long time to build an image) can I print out the logs...